# nginx appending file name in the root directory

Tags: angular, nginx

Hi I am getting 404 while trying to serve static content using nginx

here is my nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  uat.mygymchum.com;
    root /home/rc/gymchum-uat/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
    }
    error_page 404 =200 index.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
     #   root   html;
    #}
}
```

when I see error.log file, I can see this error.

```
2017/08/29 17:38:24 [error] 19404#19404: *2 open() "/home/rc/gymchum-uat/distindex.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.201.181.85, server: uat.mygymchum.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "uat.mygymchum.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}
```

to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Your default path starts with `/`. So don't miss that in static file paths